# import node request types for typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, definitelytyped, type-definition

I have a small proxy server developed in node with js and I'm trying to rewrite it in typescript.

I have the following code:

```js
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(config.port);
console.log(`proxy listening on port ${config.port}`)

function onRequest(local_req:, local_res) {
  console.log('serve: ' + local_req.url);

  const url = config.forward_url + local_req.url
[...]
```

ANd typescript complains about

Parameter 'local_req' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
   Parameter 'local_res' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

I already did `npm i @types/node -D`

I see that the definition of the createServer method is like the following:

```
function createServer(options: ServerOptions, requestListener?: RequestListener): Server;
```

But I don't have the definition of RequestListener

I google it and I find it [here](https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions/blob/master/node.d.ts#L291) (I thought it should had been installed `npm i @types/node -D`), like this:

```
export function createServer(requestListener?: (request: ServerRequest, response: ServerResponse) =>void ): Server;
```

Then I look for the definition of ServerRequest and it's [here](https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions/blob/master/node.d.ts#L239), but I don't have it available on my machine.

I guess that the definition I have goolged is not the one I have installed with npm.

I don't get how to deal with the definitions of node types.

Can anybody give me a hint about how to download the definitions of the types you are using in node?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I could solve it like this:

```
function onRequest(local_req: IncomingMessage, local_res: ServerResponse)
```

But I had to google around, finding different and incompatible version than what I had installed, and the editor (vscode)was a bit misleading about it.

I wonder if there's a better way to handle these sort of issues